# Use data from database to call an Image and use it as marker image in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Good Day, I just wanna ask something about markers.
1. I have a folder consist of 3 gif's and that is fire,carnapping and homicide
2.I also have a database,a table and inside of that I have a field name "icon_name" with other fields 3. This is my image folder location `C:\wamp\www\wew\legends`

Here is my code:

```
      function getInfo() { 
  $.getJSON("get_info.php", function (data) { 
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
      var location = new L.LatLng(data[i].lat, data[i].lng); 
      var marker = new L.Marker(location,{iconUrl: 'C:\wamp\www\New System CS\SanBartolome\wew\legends' + data[i].icon_name + '.gif'}); 
       marker.bindPopup(
          data[i].name + "<br>" + 
          data[i].user_date + "<br>" + 
          data[i].user_time + "<br>" + 
          data[i].address + "<br>"
       ).addTo(map);
       marker.on('click', function(e) { // HERE YOU GO
          var ll = marker.getLatLng();
          document.querySelector('#userLat1').value = ll.lat;
          document.querySelector('#userLng1').value = ll.lng;
          alert('You have selected a Marker that will be deleted');
       });
     } 
  });
}
```

Here is the `get_info.php`

```
<?php 
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=poi', 'root', ''); 
$sql = "SELECT name,user_date,user_time,address,lat,lng,icon_name FROM tblmarker"; 

$rs = $db->query($sql); 
if (!$rs) { 
    echo "An SQL error occured.\n"; 
    exit; 
} 

$rows = array(); 
while($r = $rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
    $rows[] = $r; 
    $name[] = $r['name'];
    $user_date[] = $r['user_date'];
    $user_time[] = $r['user_time'];
    $address[] = $r['address'];
    $icon_name[] = $r['icon_name'];
} 
print json_encode($rows); 
$db = NULL; 
?>
```

This is what it does:

1.call my `get_info.php` which consist of a code of `select * from tablename`
2.var location: get the value of lat and long in database
3.creating the marker (default marker)
4. get the data from database and transfer it in leaflet bindpop up

and the result is a default marker in a map that has been generated using the data from database.

This is my question: How can I pass the data inside my table field "icon_name" into the markers image? I mean use the icon_name data's to call the image in a folder and use it as a marker.

TYIA

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Use your own icons folder path.

```
function getInfo() { 
  $.getJSON("get_info.php", function (data) { 
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
      var location = new L.LatLng(data[i].lat, data[i].lng); 
      var marker = new L.Marker(location,{icon: '/path/to/icons/' + data[i].icon_name}); 
       marker.bindPopup(
          data[i].name + "<br>" + 
          data[i].user_date + "<br>" + 
          data[i].user_time + "<br>" + 
          data[i].address + "<br>"
       ).addTo(map);
       marker.on('click', function(e) { // HERE YOU GO
          var ll = marker.getLatLng();
          document.querySelector('#userLat1').value = ll.lat;
          document.querySelector('#userLng1').value = ll.lng;
          alert('You have selected a Marker that will be deleted');
       });
     } 
  });
}
```

Add `+ '.gif'` after `icon_name` if `icon_name` doesn't include the file extension.

Comment: its not working sir, i have a sample markers but when i replace it with you code and refresh it and nothing happens. does it something to do with the folder?

Comment: Possibly. If all it is doing is grabbing the icon name, then it's using the url path `filename.gif` and assuming it's in the current folder. You can add the folder to the original `icon_name` passed in the `data` variable, or add it in the JavaScript after retrieving `data`. Either works. Adding the folder path when sending `data` is probably a better idea since you can do more with it before `data` gets sent.

Comment: Can you show me your example using my code if its ok?

Comment: :D sir pls see my edited post i put your code together with the folder location but its not working. here is a sample image location. `C:\wamp\www\New System CS\SanBartolome\wew\legends`

Comment: Try `/wew/lengends/`. Browsers use forward slash, and if you don't add the pretending forward slash it will look for `wew` in the current folder. **e.g.** if you are on `mypage.com/home/` it will look for `mypage.com/home/wew/legends` instead of starting from the root dir.

Comment: here is the updated part of code  var marker = new L.Marker(location,{icon: '/wew/lengends/' + data[i].icon_name + '.gif'}); but when i try still not working

Comment: Try running a debug: add this at the end of that line: `console.log('icon name:', data[i].icon_name);`

Then open up your browser console (Ctrl+Shift+J in Chrome, Ctrl+Shift+K in Firefox) and see what name comes up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67394/discussion-between-paul-pagente-and-makaze).

Comment: sir here is the updated code var marker = new L.Marker(location,{icon: '/wew/lengends/' + console.log(data[i].icon_name) + '.gif'});
here is the error in the console Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)